# Scala "case map" equivalent in python

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark

How to write the following scala code in pyspark?

```
rdd1.join(rdd2.map {case ((t, w), u) => (t, (w, u))}).map {case (t, (v, (w, u))) => ((t, w), (u, v))}.collect()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use lambda functions for this:

```
rdd1 = sc.parallelize(range(1,10)).map(lambda x: (x, x+1))
rdd2 = sc.parallelize(range(1,10)).map(lambda x: ((x, x*2), x*3)))
rdd1.join(rdd2.map(lambda ((t, w), u): (t, (w, u)))).map(lambda (t, (v, (w, u))): ((t, w), (u, v))).collect()
```

Comment: It is the approach to use, not the given solution

Comment: Here is the exact solution: `rdd1 = sc.parallelize(range(1,10)).map(lambda x: (x, x+1)); rdd2 = sc.parallelize(range(1,10)).map(lambda x: ((x, x*2), x*3)); rdd1.join(rdd2.map(lambda ((t, w), u): (t, (w, u)))).map(lambda (t, (v, (w, u))): ((t, w), (u, v))).collect()`

Comment: You should update the answer with this precise one. then it is a worthy solution.